# Regarding installation of iOS application in a real device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I've been fixing my application to run in real iOS device. I am using Xcode organizer. Now when i use it, it gives me this error:

> xcode cannot find the software image to install this version

My iPhone version is: 6.0.1
My Xcode version is: 3.2.3

Any ideas how to solve this? I've already tried re-plugging the phone, I've also check some troubleshooting that other devs provided but it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.3 was released approximately when iOS 4 was out, so it won't support iOS 6.

Actual version is (at least) 4.5.1

Download it from the Mac App Store or [here](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).